# PyQt QListView retrieving item after item edited by user interface

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qlistview, pyqt5

I'm working with Python 3.3 PyQt5. I have an QListView widget which is contains some items. I want to retrieve item when user double-click to item and edit it so I can save its new value to a database. But I can't find any SIGNAL like edit finished or something useful.

```
class MainWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    itemName = ""
    def __init__(self, inheritance=None):
        super(MainWin, self).__init__()
        self.ui=uic.loadUi("MainWin.ui", self)

        self.wordList = FileProc.WordStorage().readWordFile()

        self.showListView()
        self.itemName = ""

    def showListView(self, file = 'wordlist.db'):
        MainWin.wordList = FileProc.WordStorage().readWordFile(file)

        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self.listView)

        for row in MainWin.wordList:
            item = QtGui.QStandardItem(row)
            model.appendRow(item)

        self.listView.setModel(model)

    def editWord(self):
        itemIndex = self.listView.selectedIndexes()
        MainWin.itemName = itemIndex[0].data()
```

I displayed list within this way. I want to retrieve edited word with editWord() method. How can I execute editWord() after item in the listView changed?

Comment: Post your code to see what have you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i would rather do when i work with Model View programming. is make the Model rather than using the default ones.

```
class ListMOdel(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self , data=[] ,parent=None):
        QtCore.QAbstractListModel.__init__(self,parent)
        self.__data=data

    def rowCount(self ,parent):
        return len(self.__data)

    def data(self,index,role):

        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            row=index.row()
            value = self.__data[row]
            return value

    def flags(self,index):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable |QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled| QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable

    def setData(self,index,value,role=QtCore.Qt.EditRole):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            row= index.row()
            self.__data[row]=value
            return True
        return False

class MainWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    itemName = ""
    def __init__(self, inheritance=None):
        super(MainWin, self).__init__()
        self.ui=uic.loadUi("MainWin.ui", self)

        self.wordList = FileProc.WordStorage().readWordFile()

        self.showListView()
        self.itemName = ""

    def showListView(self, file = 'wordlist.db'):
        MainWin.wordList = FileProc.WordStorage().readWordFile(file)
        data=[]
        for row in MainWin.wordList:
            data.append(row)

        model = ListMOdel(data)
        self.listView.setModel(model)
```

This is an example of customized Model. The setData function updates the value.

Comment: 'return value.name()' in data() method giving AttributeError. Why .name() used there?

Comment: Ok but, i can't get how I use it when user edited items in list within interface. I'm not having difficulties with setting data my problem is I can't find proper signal or something similar emitted when value of item changed by user interface.

Comment: @tugyan : what do you want to do with the signal. It might be heard to capture the signal , But the documentation states the following " The dataChanged() signal should be emitted if the data was successfully set. ".